# React: Immutable.js vs JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, immutable.js, stringify

Currently I run into problem with `React 'shouldComponentUpdate'` method - I noticed that I pass arguments to that function by links. Therefore I couldn't use any optimizations since I have nextProps and this.props as the same thing.

My question is - how should I argue with my colleague to convince him to use Immutable data structures to pass around instead just copying objects with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)`? Is there are any benchmarks which compare this ways to solve the problem?

Comment: hmmm aren't React docs enough convincing for your colleague ?!! and honestly I expect someone to complain about Immutable data with "too much copying" but if your colleague already does too much `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)` then what is his/her complain ?

Comment: @niceman Could you please point in react docs where said that using [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#using-immutable-data-structures) is prefered way to solve this problem instead of using spread characters, Object.assign or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())? It will be helpful.

Comment: it's in the official tutorial : https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to copy objects by stringifying then parsing; that's bound to be slower than doing deep copies, although I haven't benchmarked. Why not just benchmark on jsperf or similar?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on app specifics and pretty-much opinion based. If your app state is like 10-20 boolean flags spread op would work just perfect. On the other hand if you have deeply nested (say graph-like) structures in it with circular refs stringify/parse would simply fail.

Comment: @niceman, thank you for sharing this link, but unfortunately it is too general and doesn't correlate with my question. I already know importance of immutable data - the question is how I manage it. My question was "Is there are any benchmarks", not about importance of immutable data. Nevertheless thank you for your time.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thank you for your reply! I did benchmark right when I met this problem. But I think that I missed something, because results tells that stringify/parse works faster than Immutable's .fromJS(). Please, point me where I did mistake, here is [the link on JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/json-parse-json-stringify-vs-immutable).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, thank you for your answer! Could you please comment [this link to JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/json-parse-json-stringify-vs-immutable)? I'm sure that I misunderstand something, but right now it seems that stringifying/parsing looks faster than Immutable's .fromJS(). Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MichaelPachin I didn't say immutable would be faster, I said a deep copy would be faster (and even that's just a guess; could easily be wrong). In addition, how the data is being manipulated has a strong impact on whether or not immutablejs will be faster/slower.

Comment: @MichaelPachin It seems that test only measures initial state creation. What about update operations? For example you need to change `data[1].email`. BTW I never said immutablejs is about performance. I say it is about consistent API.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, Thank you for your reply. I tried benchmark lodash, immutable and parse/stringify [in this JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/react-object-cloning). It seems that stringify/parse is faster than other in Chrome and Immutable.js is slowest. I was discouraged by this result but I found [this topic on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4tnie1/what_is_the_benefit_of_immutablejs/) and finally I understand that Immutable definately not about speed but about robust API, and in couple with Redux it really shines.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for your reply and your time. You were right in your assumption that deeply cloning may be slower than parse/stringify. You can check my [benchmark on JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/react-object-cloning). Despite that Immutable is slowest there I should noticed that [this discussion on Reddit was eye-opening for me](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4tnie1/what_is_the_benefit_of_immutablejs/). Now I understand that the story with Immutable.js is not about speed but about robust API, and coupled with Redux it is really a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that stringify/parse is faster than other in Chrome and Immutable.js is slowest ([JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/react-object-cloning)). I was discouraged by this result but I found [this topic on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4tnie1/what_is_the_benefit_of_immutablejs/) and finally I understand that **Immutable definitely not about speed but about robust API** and in couple with Redux it really shines.
Also I should highlight this thought from pointed Reddit discussion:

> don't forget this is JavaScript, and every browser has multiple layers
>   of optimizations- meaning that what is fast or slow today might be
>   slow or fast tomorrow (within reason)